# Event Driven Angular to State Management Reactive NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs

Well, as an old-school coder, we are done to some recipes actually successful with daily issues. One of them is the creation of a "master record" (if it doesn't exist) and save it to the API before adding items to it. 
As posting to an API is being put aside as "side actions" on new "state management" patterns, this actual code in one of my services:

```js
// removed meaningless code and simplified as verbal 
// functions some careless code operations

// tries to find if there is any cart available
// if so, retrieves it, else creates a new one

let existingCart = anyExistingCartAvailable();
if (existingCart) {
   cart = exisingCart;
} else {
   cart = new cart();
   // Post the cart to get the Id on the DB.
   PostCart(cart);
}

selectedItemsArray.foreach(item => {
    cart.Items.push(itemUpdateCartId(item))
});

PostCart(cart);
```

Now, with NGXS and State Management, I'm trying something like this:

```js
let existingCart = anyExistingCartAvailable();
if (existingCart) {
   cart = exisingCart;
} else {
   cart = new cart();
}

const cartSubs = store.select(CurrentCart).subscribe((cCart) => {
   selectedItemsArray.foreach(item => {
    cart.Items.push(itemUpdateCartId(item))
   });
   // Don't want to get into the subscription again
   cartSubs.unsubscribe();
   // Update cart header and items.
   store.dispatch(new PostCart(cCart));
});   

// As it's in the same store, It will trigger the "CurrentCart" select.
store.dispatch(new PostCart(cart));
```

But when I step through the code, it gets into the subscription code before dispatching the new `PostCart()` action at the bottom.
Tried with `.pipe(skip(1))` RxJS operator, but then no selector is triggered.

Even I've posted one code example -as was usual to solve this scenario-, and the actual code following the new "State Management" paradigm, that fails, I can't imagine how this question could be more clear.

This is not an "orthographic" or "compiler error" question, so I need to ask more on a "philosophical" way.

**I need to post a new cart and get an ID from the API before adding items.**

But posting as a side action thru State Management (NGXS) I can't know when the async object is done.

Is there a way to put the code that has to be executed when the post of the "master" instance is finished? How can we solve this on NGXS?

Comment: It will be of help if we can answer in a teaching way more than trying to full our SO portfolio proving how smart we are.

Comment: I had a previous question closed so three reputed guys felt frustrated with my style, so I had to follow their directives and ask under their guides. Now the question is as as clear as it was, but I want to evidence that I had to rewrite it removing or changing some expressions as they don't feel bad.

Comment: this is pretty much the same post found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638831/angular-ngxs-rxjs-dispatch-finish-event ......   I suspect you may be violating the CQRS pattern, which Is why I asked if i understood your intent in the other question you posted.  I am not really concerned with earning points on SO, but if you wish to get better assistance please answer.  Why not default your state to a reasonable value and then add your selected items to the cart and then dispatch your action to the store.  From here your CurrentCart would have the new items.

Comment: Maybe this time they remove my comments which I will write again until I get my account banned.

Comment: https://www.ngxs.io/#what-is-ngxs

Comment: It is still intended to follow CQRS

Comment: Sorry @Chris Hayley, had a confusion with your name!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209472/discussion-between-chris-hailey-and-josep-alacid).

Comment: That's why I am asking. Maybe some one can translate that old recipe to the new CQRS pattern so we have a concrete example of how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I would suggest that you default your CurrentCart to something reasonable and then add your selectedItems to cart and dispatch PostCart action.  From here your CurrentCard state will fire notifications through Selectors and anyone subscribing to it will have the new values.  Picture a big circle.  Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Let's write it with other words:
First I need to have a valid "CurrentCart" (creating one if there is no active cart) and then I need to add Items to it.
When I have to subscribe to "CurrentCart" to get the valid one?
I can't write this as a question. Maybe as a comment.